# How does chrome detect login text boxes?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a textBox, that is supposed to get an `url` from an user.
Unfortunately, chrome autofills it with saved login name.

I would like to understand how chrome detects login input? How can I stop chrome filling this textbox?

My textbox does not have  **'login'** in `Id` or `name`. I could set `autocomplete="off"` or `autocomplete = "false"` for the input but I do not think it solves the problem. Tomorrow another textbox may be treated as login and I will have to redeploy code again. I need to prevent chrome thinking the input is a login textbox.

Comment: Can you show your form code so that we can test it on our side?

Comment: It will not be easy. Form is created in a APS.NET WebForms. And I would not like to share it, because the code belongs to the corporate.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of autocomplete="off" use autocomplete="false"

Setting the autocomplete attribute to "off" does not disable Chrome autofill in more recent versions of Chrome.

Comment: It doesn't answer my questions. I mentioned the possibility of using autocomplete property

Comment: who say : How can I stop chrome filling this textbox.I could set autocomplete="off" for the input but I do not think it solves the problem. ?  you mentionned that you use autocomplete="off" but you need to use autocomplete="false

Comment: The questions is: how does chrome detect login textbox. Have you answered this question?

Comment: I answered : How can I stop chrome filling this textbox? have you posted this questions ? use autocomplete="false" instead of autocomplete="off" and you will prevent chrome filling it.  thank you

Comment: I edited the question. Are you able to understand the problem now?